# Display county for random points

Tags: csv, point-in-polygon, spatial-join

I have a county level shapefile for South Carolina. I generated random points using `Vector->Research Tools-> Random Points`. The attribute tables for the random points layer has only the ID included.

I would like to export the latitude, longitude and corresponding county for all the generated points (there is a COUNTYFP10 variable in the attributes table of the original state layer).

I managed to export the latitude and longitude using "Save as", choosing "Comma Separated Value".  Then, in the "Layers" part of the "OGR creation options" I typed "GEOMETRY=AS_XY".

I am not sure how to add the corresponding county to the saved CSV file.

Answer (score 2):

Could you take the generated points and go to Vector -> Data management Tools -> Join Attributes by Location? That would add the county name to each point. Then export the points out to a CSV. I tested this with QGIS 1.8.